# Dynamically changing div alignment inside a flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a `<ul>` element as flex container with row direction. Each `<li>` element has a menu contained inside a div, that opens up towards the right when some event occurs.

The problem, is that from some `<li>` onwards, the menu flows outside the right side of the flex container boundaries.

What I want, is that the menu will know when to stretch rightward from its parent `<li>`, and when to stretch leftward, depending on whether enough space is still available on the right or not.

This is a skeleton of the problem scope:

```
<ul style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-start;">
    <li ng-repeat="items-in-some-source">
        <div>
            <!-- some stuff -->
            <div>
                <!-- some other stuff -->
            </div>
            <div style="position:relative;" ng-include="some-menu-template.html"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the expected result, with menu closed on the top row, and some examples with an open menu on the following rows. Note how the `<li id=D>` element behaves, and also note that the number of `<li>` elements is dynamic:

[image]

This is what happens now, notice how `<li id=D>` overflows the flex container:

[image]

So, is there any way to achieve this using just css? I prefer not to use a Javascript solution for this.

Comment: can you add a snippet / fiddle too?